# UnityのPhotonで自分以外のPlayerのCanvasが混じらないようにしたい。

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityのPhotonを使って人狼型オンラインゲームを作ろうとしています。
役職をそれぞれのPlayerに与えるまではよかったのですが、それをそれぞれのPlayerの画面に表示すると、役職が正しく表示されません。
エラーは発生していません。

## コード

```
public PhotonView photonView;
public GameObject jobUI;

if(!photonView.isMine) {
   jobUI.SetActive(false);
} else {
   jobUI.SetActive(true);
}

public IEnumerator JobOnGUI(GameObject player)
{
    jobUI.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    Text jobText = jobUI.transform.Find("JobText").GetComponent<Text>();
    jobText.text = player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().GetJob().ToString();
}
```

初心者なのでかなり書式がぐちゃぐちゃです。

## 試したこと

PhotonViewのついたPlayerのプレハブの子要素に役職表示用のUIを入れて、Instantiateしています。
photonViewにはPlayerについているものを入れて、jobUIには、Canvasの子要素にあるPanelを入れています。Panelの子要素にJobTextがあります。
JobTextのtextには、PlayerController(プレーヤー制御用のスクリプト)の役職の列挙型をそのまま入れています。
GameManagerのほうで役職の設定は行い(ここも正しく機能している)、このコルーチンを呼び出しています。

## 結果

それぞれのプレイヤーのjobTextには、正しい役職が入っているのですが、実際に表示されている役職が違います。

Answer (score 1):

> PhotonViewのついたPlayerのプレハブの子要素に役職表示用のUIを入れて、Instantiateしています。

この Instantiate は **PhotonNetwork.Instantiate** メソッドのことですよね？その場合、そのような処理では、その「役職表示用のUI」は全員の UI に表示されてしまいます。

もちろん Player のプレハブは全クライアントに対して生成したいでしょうが、UI は自分自身にだけ生成してやればよいと思います。

つまり、UI 部分だけ別のプレハブにして、Player が Instantiate される時に、 PhotonView.isMine == true を満たす時だけ、UI のプレハブを Instantiate (**[Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)**) してやる、ということです。この時、UI のプレハブに PhotonView コンポーネントは必要ありません。